# Texto aparece por trás do menu

Tags: html, css

Eu tenho uma menu e o meu texto da página está aparecer por trás do menu e eu quero que apareça ao lado.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Código da página é:

```
<html>

<heard>
<meta charset='utf-8'>
   <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
   <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
   <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
   <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
   <script src="script.js"></script>

<title>Fernardo Pessoa - Vida</title>

</heard>

<body background="imagens/fundopessoa1.png">
   <div id='cssmenu'>
      <ul>
         <li><a href='inicio.html'><span>Inicio</span></a></li>
         <li><a href='vida.html'><span>Biografia</span></a></li>
         <li class='active has-sub'><a href=""><span>Obras Poéticas</span></a>
            <ul>
           <li><a href='ortonimo.html'><span>Ortónimo</span></a></li>
               <li class='has-sub'><a href=""><span>Heterónimos</span></a>
                  <ul>
                     <li><a href='AlvaroCampos.html'><span>Álvaro de Campos</span></a></li>
                     <li class='last'><a href='RicardoReis'><span>Ricardo Reis</span></a></li>
                     <li class='last'><a href='AlbertoCaeiro'><span>Alberto Caeiro</span></a></li>
                  </ul>
               </li>
            </ul>
     </li>
         <li class='last'><a href='crologia'><span>Crologogia</span></a></li>
      </ul>
   </div>

   <div>   
      <h1 align="center"><font color="green"><b>Fernando Pessoa</center></b></font></h1>
      <p><font color="blue" face="Verdana" size="4">Fernando Antônio Nogueira Pessoa foi um dos mais importantes escritores e poetas do modernismo em Portugal. Nasceu a 13 de Junho de 1888 na cidade de Lisboa(Portugal) e morreu, na mesma cidade, a 30 de NOvembro de 1935.
      <p>Fernando Pessoa foi morar, ainda infância, na mesma cidade Durban (África do Sul), onde seu pai tornou-se cônsul. Neste país teve contacto com a língua e literatura inglesa.
      <p>Adulto, Fernando Pessoa trabalhou como tradutor técnico, publicando seus primeiros poemas em Inglês.
      <p>Em 1905, retornou sozinho para Lisboa,e na ano seguinte, matriculou-se no curso superior de Letras. Porém, abandou o curso um ano depois.
      <p>Pessoa passou a ter um ontacto mais efetivo com a literatura portuguesa, principalmente <a href="PadreVieira.html">Padre Antônio Vieira</a> e <a href="CesarioVerde.html">Cesário Verde</a>. Foi também influênciado pelos estudos filosóficos de Nietzsche e Schopenhuer. Recebeu também influências do simbolismo francês.
      <p>Em 1912, começou suas atividades como ensaísta e crítico literário, na revista Águia.
      <p>A saúde do poeta português começou a apresentar complicações em 1935. Neste anoo foi hospitalizado com cólica hepática, provalmente causada pelo consumo excessivo de bebida alcoólica.</font>
   </div>
</body>

</html>
```

E o código para gerar o menu é:

```
#cssmenu,
#cssmenu ul,
#cssmenu ul li,
#cssmenu ul li a {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  border: 0;
  list-style: none;
  line-height: 1;
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
#cssmenu {
  width: 200px;
  font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  float:left;
  z-index:20;
  position: absolute;
  color: #000000;
}
#cssmenu ul ul {
  display: none;
}
.align-right {
  float: right;
}
#cssmenu > ul > li > a {
  padding: 15px 20px;
  border-left: 1px solid #444444;
  border-right: 1px solid #444444;
  border-top: 1px solid #444444;
  cursor: pointer;
  z-index: 2;
  font-size: 14px;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #ffffff;
  text-shadow: 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.35);
  background: #ffffff;
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(#444444, #333333);
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(#444444, #333333);
  background: -o-linear-gradient(#444444, #333333);
  background: -ms-linear-gradient(#444444 #333333);
  background: linear-gradient(#444444, #333333);
  box-shadow: inset 0 1px 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.15);
}
#cssmenu > ul > li > a:hover,
#cssmenu > ul > li.active > a,
#cssmenu > ul > li.open > a {
  color: #ffffff;
  background: #ffffff;
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(#444444, #333333);
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(#444444, #333333);
  background: -o-linear-gradient(#444444, #333333);
  background: -ms-linear-gradient(#444444 #333333);
  background: linear-gradient(#444444, #333333);
}
#cssmenu > ul > li.open > a {
  box-shadow: inset 0 1px 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.15), 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);
  border-bottom: 1px solid #000000;
}
#cssmenu > ul > li:last-child > a,
#cssmenu > ul > li.last > a {
  border-bottom: 1px solid #333333;
}
.holder {
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
}
.holder::after,
.holder::before {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  content: "";
  width: 6px;
  height: 6px;
  right: 20px;
  z-index: 10;
  -webkit-transform: rotate(-135deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(-135deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(-135deg);
  -o-transform: rotate(-135deg);
  transform: rotate(-135deg);
}
.holder::after {
  top: 17px;
  border-top: 2px solid #000000;
  border-left: 2px solid #000000;
}
#cssmenu > ul > li > a:hover > span::after,
#cssmenu > ul > li.active > a > span::after,
#cssmenu > ul > li.open > a > span::after {
  border-color: #ffffff;
}
.holder::before {
  top: 18px;
  border-top: 2px solid;
  border-left: 2px solid;
  border-top-color: inherit;
  border-left-color: inherit;
}
#cssmenu ul ul li a {
  cursor: pointer;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #000000;
  border-left: 1px solid #000000;
  border-right: 1px solid #000000;
  padding: 10px 20px;
  z-index: 1;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 13px;
  color: #ffffff;
  background: #666666;
  box-shadow: inset 0 1px 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.1);
}
#cssmenu ul ul ul li a {
  cursor: pointer;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #000000;
  border-left: 1px solid #000000;
  border-right: 1px solid #000000;
  padding: 10px 20px;
  z-index: 1;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 13px;
  color: #ffffff;
  background: #888888;
  box-shadow: inset 0 1px 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.1);
}
#cssmenu ul ul li:hover > a,
#cssmenu ul ul li.open > a,
#cssmenu ul ul li.active > a {
  background: #666666;
  color: #ffffff;
}
#cssmenu ul ul li:first-child > a {
  box-shadow: none;
}
#cssmenu ul ul ul li:first-child > a {
  box-shadow: inset 0 1px 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.1);
}
#cssmenu ul ul ul li a {
  padding-left: 30px;
}
#cssmenu > ul > li > ul > li:last-child > a,
#cssmenu > ul > li > ul > li.last > a {
  border-bottom: 0;
}
#cssmenu > ul > li > ul > li.open:last-child > a,
#cssmenu > ul > li > ul > li.last.open > a {
  border-bottom: 1px solid #32373e;
}
#cssmenu > ul > li > ul > li.open:last-child > ul > li:last-child > a {
  border-bottom: 0;
}
#cssmenu ul ul li.has-sub > a::after {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  content: "";
  width: 5px;
  height: 5px;
  right: 20px;
  z-index: 10;
  top: 11.5px;
  border-top: 2px solid #eeeeee;
  border-left: 2px solid #eeeeee;
  -webkit-transform: rotate(-135deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(-135deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(-135deg);
  -o-transform: rotate(-135deg);
  transform: rotate(-135deg);
}
#cssmenu ul ul li.active > a::after,
#cssmenu ul ul li.open > a::after,
#cssmenu ul ul li > a:hover::after {
  border-color: #ffffff;
}
```

Comment: se possível @CatarinaSilveste, poste o código que você usa para gerar o menu

Comment: @CatarinaSilvestre, te aconselho olhar o seguinte codepen: http://codepen.io/SitePoint/pen/uIemr, talvez lhe ajude.

Comment: Eu com a resposta do @Renilson Andrade eu já consegui resolver o que queria mas agora eu gostaria de por uma margem também do lado direito, mas não consigo o que eu tentei foi .menu { float: left; width: 30%; top: 20%;}
.conteudo { float: right; width: 70%; height: 100%;}.

Comment: você pode adicionar uma segunda div com float: right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você pode trabalhar com a propriedade **float**, e dimensionar de acordo com sua necessidade.

Adicione este código em seu CSS:

```
.menu { float: left; width: 30%; top: 20%;}
.conteudo { float: right; width: 70%; }
```

Referencie o css nas divs específicas:

```
<div id='cssmenu' class="menu">
...
</div>
<div class="conteudo">   
...
</div>
```

[Exemplo](http://jsfiddle.net/randrade/2q16095a/1/)

Answer (score 0):

Não sei se vai te ajudar, mas se esse menu for de largura fixa você pode colocar uma margem esquerda no container dos textos.

```
.classe-da-div-com-textos{
     margin-left: 150px; //essa é a largura do menu
}
```

Não é a solução mais bonita, porém deve funcionar. Leia sobre a propriedade [float](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_class_float.asp) e mais adiante sobre [grid](http://tableless.com.br/grids-semanticos-com-less/).